# Import CSS and JS theme files to a controller page

Tags: magento-1.9, javascript, css, controllers, rwd-theme

Let's say that we have this controller :

```
<?php
class Hello_World_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        echo 'Hello Stackers !' ;
    }
}
```

Obviously, when triggering this controller, we will have a black message `Hello Stackers !`, and the controller page is not having/importing any theme (JS, CSS) files even in the default (rwd) Magento theme .

How can we import theme in controllers pages ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following between the `loadLayout` and the `renderLayout` method calls:

```
// In case of a JS file under the /js folder
$this->getLayout()->getBlock('head')->addJs('my.js');
// In case of a JS file under the /skin folder
$this->getLayout()->getBlock('head')->addItem('skin_js','my.js');
// In case of a CSS file under the /skin folder
$this->getLayout()->getBlock('head')->addItem('skin_css','my.css');
```

If you only need the default theme you need to update your code with the following:

```
$this->loadLayout();
$this->renderLayout();
```

Comment: In that case, the theme's header and footer will be also loaded. What if we want to have an empty page, displaying only `Hello Stackers !`, and importing the desired JS/CSS files ? EDIT: Just like creating an empty design layout page from CMS-Pages .

Comment: @androniennn see my updated answer.

Comment: Your edit will load the header and footer. What about just echo the message without header and footer. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @androniennn you should never use `echo` directly in your controller, here's why: http://magento.stackexchange.com/q/110845/2380